# A DFA that depends on a natural number

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

Given a natural number $m$, I'm asked to find a DFA that accepts the language of words over Σ = {0, 1} such that the $m$th
character from the end is 1. (The answer has to depend on $m$)
This is a question I was given in one of my homework assignments, therefore I'd really like some **hints** on this one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know what a shift register is?

Comment: Hey Fabio!  I havne't heard of the term. It's the first homework in the course :( (computational models)

Comment: It's a device in which you store the input bits one at a time.  Every time a new bit of input arrives, the current bits shift to the right and the new bit is stored in the leftmost position. (or the other way around; it doesn't really matter).  I asked because that's what you've been asked to design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DFA that accepts a word in $\{\,0,1\,\}^*$ if the $m$-th input character from the end is $1$ must remember the last $m$ characters that it read.  That is, there must be a state for each of the $2^m$ possible words in $\{\,0,1\,\}^*$ of length $m$.  While looking at the state graphs of the DFAs for small values of $m$ may not immediately suggest a rule, these automata have a simple, regular structure.

First of all, they can be implemented as *shift registers*: registers that store the last $m$ input bits that were read.  Every time a new bit of input is read, the current bits shift to the left and the new bit is stored in the rightmost position.  The oldest (leftmost) bit is lost.  The state of the DFA is given by the register's content.  Whether the DFA is accepting depends on the oldest bit.  The initial state is the one with $0$s in all positions.

Armed with this intuition, if we interpret the contents of the register as a number in base 2, we can then give a simple formula for the next-state function of the DFA.  Let the set of states of the DFA be $Q = \{\,0,\ldots,2^{m-1}\,\}$.  Let $b$ be the input bit, and let $\delta\colon Q \times \{\, 0,1\,\} \to Q$ be the next state function; then

$$ \delta(q,b) = (2q+b) \bmod 2^m\enspace. $$

You should be able to complete the formal description of the DFA without too much trouble from here.

You should also try to understand the claim I made at the beginning, that these DFAs do need $2^m$ states.

Comment: Hey Fabio! Thank you for taking the time answering my question. What do you mean by saying that these DFAs need 2^m states? aren't the stated states are m states?

Comment: There are $m$ state bits that can be in any of $2^m$ configurations.  For $m=3$, $000, 001, 010, \ldots, 110, 111$.  If you were to draw the state diagram of the DFA for $m=3$, you'd draw eight circles and sixteen arrows.  For example, from state $110$ you'd go to either $100$ or $101$ depending on whether you shifted in a $0$ or a $1$.  You should try it. You'd get a much better appreciation for what these DFAs do.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but what happens if I change the request from the m-th number being 1 to 0? I've tried building a DFA using the Q you've mentioned but I fail to do so..What is the initial state? the accepted states?

Comment: You can reason thus.  The shortest accepted word is of length $m$.  If I start from $2^m-1$ ($m$ ones), it takes at least $m$ input characters to replace the leftmost $1$ with a $0$.  Then I accept whenever that "oldest" bit is $0$ once all the input has been read.  In other words, you just swap the roles of $0$ and $1$ in the initial and accepting states.  In fact, starting from the state diagram of the DFA that looks for a $1$, you can get the state graph for the DFA that looks for a $0$ by changing all zeros into ones and vice versa in your drawing.  (It's just renaming the input symbols.)